# Showing that if $f(u)$ is algebraic then $u$ is algebraic as well

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a field and $f\in F[X]$ is a non-constant polynomial and let $u\in F$.

I am trying to show that if $f(u)$ is algebraic over $F$ then $u$ is also algebraic over $F$. I'm not sure how to tackle this question. I know that if $u^2$ is algebraic then $u$ is algebraic, but I am not sure if that is applicable here.

Comment: If $f(u)$ is algebraic, then there is a polynomial $p$ such that $p(f(u)) = 0$.

Comment: Therefore, $u$ is algebraic, with the corresponding polynomial being $p \circ f$.

Comment: Of course! I had convinced myself that the composition wasn't a polynomial for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: @DHMO: $p \neq 0$ should be added and the remark that then $p \circ f \neq 0$ too. This requires some reasoning.

Comment: @Dman: I think that you mean something else. $u$ is contained in $F$, so it is algebraic for trivial reaons. Please edit accordingly.